# Objective C error at ObjectAtIndex Array

Tags: objective-c

i have a problem with Objective C code, i recieve these errors.

```
 2013-01-31 16:22:53.611 iSA-MP[541:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7465d70
2013-01-31 16:22:53.614 iSA-MP[541:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception               'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7465d70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c8c012 0x10c9e7e 0x1d174bd 0x1c7bbbc 0x1c7b94e 0x2163 0xf2817 0xf2882 0x41a25 0x41dbf             0x41f55 0x4af67 0xefcc 0xffab 0x21315 0x2224b 0x13cf8 0x1be7df9 0x1be7ad0 0x1c01bf5 0x1c01962 0x1c32bb6 0x1c31f44 0x1c31e1b 0xf7da 0x1165c 0x1dbd 0x1ce5) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

with this code:

```
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.125:100/isa-mp/iSA-MP.php?serverIP=192.168.0.125&serverPort=7777"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Your data which you are getting from url is not in Array format

Comment: I presume the error is occurring when executing the __NSLog__ line at the end. Have you looked at __array__ in the debugger to make sure it is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being returned a Dictionary, if you don't know the contents of your data you are recieved, NSLog `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]` and check the key for the item that you want to be array.

You might want to do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *array = dict[@"someKeyForArray"];
```

Comment: Alright, this works. Although i receive a warning on my code line with *dict declartion, Incompatible pointer types initializng NSDictionary with an expression of type NSMutableArray

Comment: oh right, ill update my answer sorry! Remove the type casting from `NSJSONSerialization`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your calling objectAtIndex: on an NSDictionary...

It looks like the problem resides in your JSON that you are parsing, the JSON will be formatted so that parsing it returns an NSDictionary. Even though you are casting to an Array it will still be a Dictionary behind the scenes.

Comment: Hey, when i just print out the array variable, i get the whole json array. But how would i fix it so i can get like "map"